# How is reputation computed when new user has a lot of downvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Imagine this situation:

- A new user arrives on Stack Overflow.
- They ask a bad question and get 10 downvotes. That's -20 rep, but they stay at 1 because you can't get lower.
- They ask a second, better question that earns 5 upvotes.

What is their final reputation? Is it 1 + 25 from the upvotes = 26 ? Or is it 1 + 25 from the upvotes - 20 from the downvotes = 6 ?

I have searched a bit on Meta but didn't find a related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation changes are applied in the order they occur, so in this case the user will end up with a reputation of 26.

It took me a while to find an example, but [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460005/laura-g?tab=reputation):

[image]